# Manipulate URL with subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I need some help. I have an existing website. I made an admin site using laravel. both are different project. Here is want I want

I have a site called www.mywebsite.com

I created a symlink of my subsite that was made with laravel on to public_html of mywebsite.com

so you can access it like this

```
mywebsite.com/subsite/
```

subsite symlink points  to public folder of my laravel project

there is a special route in my laravel project 'admin'

I wanted it to be the default route when accessing

```
mywebsite.com/subsite/
```

and not

`mywebsite.com/subsite/admin`

other routes are  in use, so I can't rename 'admin' to root

this seems not working for folders. any thoughts. also it should still accept parameters

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^subsite? /subsite/admin [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

it seems that folders have high priority. so i renamed my subsite to project

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^subsite? /project/admin [QSA,NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

tried this also

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^subsite? /project/index.php/admin [QSA,NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

now both of them returns a 404 error from my sub project laravel. so it looks like working but not the laravel routes

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^subsite/?$ /subsite/admin [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @User101 could you be more specific  please?

Comment: subsite is a symlink on my laravel public folder. i think folders and symlinks have high priority. the RewriteRule didn't work. I can still access all the laravel routes in mysite.com/subsite where is should just return the admin view

Comment: @User101 okay, I have commented out the conditions, try the updated rule.

Comment: Thanks mate. still didn't work. I had to rename subsite folder to something

Answer (score 0):

My bad. this one was working. and I forgot to save the file. the problem is that laravel image url on blade is not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^subsite? /project/index.php/admin [QSA,NC,L]
        </IfModule>
```